# Android Studio: String text showing in studio, but not showing in App on phone

Tags: textview

I have been coding a wildlife app, and have hit a snag. I have done the images etc, but having issues displaying the text after my table. Still fairly new to this, so please bear with me. The ** part of the textview is what I am having issues with. It displays in the studio software on computer, but not on the phone. I am using a Huawei Mate 9 and a Galaxy Note 10+ 5G

here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".ui.lion.LionFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/lions"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView2"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border">

        <TextView
            android:padding="4dip"
            android:text="@string/data_lion_scientific"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="@string/data_lion" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border">

        <TextView
            android:padding="4dip"
            android:text="@string/data_lion_weight"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="@string/data_lion_values" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border">

        <TextView
            android:padding="4dip"
            android:text="@string/data_lion_gestation"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="@string/data_lion_gesLife" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
    
    **<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_lion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/data_lion_text"
        android:textSize="25sp" />**


  </RelativeLayout>

  </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have discovered that I had to have a second text view. It works now.I actually learn more by correcting my mistakes. Long live Android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"

tools:context=".ui.lion.LionFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/lions"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView2"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border">

        <TextView
            android:padding="4dip"
            android:text="@string/data_lion_scientific"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="@string/data_lion" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border">

        <TextView
            android:padding="4dip"
            android:text="@string/data_lion_weight"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="@string/data_lion_values" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border">

        <TextView
            android:padding="4dip"
            android:text="@string/data_lion_gestation"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="@string/data_lion_gesLife" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_lion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    **<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border2"
        android:text="@string/data_lion_text"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>**

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_below="@id/text2"
        android:src="@drawable/leo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


 </RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```